# Javascript: How to highlight some numbers or text within a line or paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the nth-child to add red to some specific numbers and it not working.
Can someone show how  this can be fixed or alternate way to do this using JQuery or CSS?
As thisis being generated. Is there a way to select a range to highlight some numbers?

```
p.range:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+4) {
 color:red;
}

<p class="range"> 123345232</p>
```

the output should be
only 233 should be red

Comment: What is the expected selection?

Comment: [`:nth-child` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) looks for the HTML nodes **not** the text content. One approach is wrapping each number by a `<span>` element and trying to select the correct `<span>`.

Comment: the number are being generated.  .. i had tried <span class="range">12345678</span>

Comment: @user244394 If they're being generated try to put each number in a separate `<span>` element like so:
`<p class="range"> <span>1</span><span>2</span>...</p>` and the selector would be:
`p.range > span:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+4)`. **[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/fadoc/2/edit)**.

Comment: @hashem - Thanks . but I cant insert span as its being generates random number for example : $7005679.456 . I was hoping there is simpler way to just highlight a specific range of numbers.

Comment: @user244394 Unfortunately at this time there's no CSS solution for selecting the content. But you can achieve that by using JavaScript.

Comment: @hashem - How would u do that using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a little bit of jQuery to add a `<span>` aroud each number. This code will do it (if you're already using jquery):

```
var numbers = $(".range").html().replace(/\s/g, '').split("");
var spans = "<span>" + numbers.join("</span>\n<span>") + "</span>";
$(".range").html(spans);
```

And the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/5w6hmr6f/2/). <strike>I did not make the CSS though, I leave that for you</strike>. A slight modification to the CSS you provided made it work fine with the javascript.